# faster way to type lambda symbol

Tags: visual-studio, lambda

sounds a bit silly and petty to ask, and ironically I am sure that by typing out this SO question I have actually lost more time than I could potentially gain :)

but something I was just wondering if other visual studio guys have solved this scenario

when writing out a lot of lambda function (especially when doing a fluent config) it just feels very inefficient to type out a lambda, the equals character is on the top number row of the keyboard, and the greater than sign is all he way on the down by the spacebar, and it requires using the shift at the seem time.

just feels cumbersome,

just wondering if someone knows how to build a macro or shortcut. I would much rather double tap a key or something like that. it would allow for much faster typing

(note: i am using both VS 2010 and 2012)

Comment: couldnt make a macro for this. tried a code snippet so than when i type lm<space> i get a lambda. this is better but feels quirky. looked on google for a plugin of sorts. just feels like a billion other developers should have hit this one before me

Comment: Why does lm<space> feel quirky?  What would you prefer?  Also, if you have resharper have you checked out live templates?

Comment: If you could get used to it, you *could* remap your keyboard so that the keys are next to each other. This is a perverse thing to do, and your colleagues won't thank you for it if they need to take over typing. But I do it on my own keyboard for other things (Basically, I've remapped the caps lock key on my keyboard to be "shift", not "caps lock" so as not to be stateful, and being located between 3 keys I use a *lot* as a programmer - Shift, Tab and A).

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of options 
A. Can use autohotey to send a key when you press another 'hot key' or registry remap

http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm This is a one to one re map

B. use auto hot key to send the key when you press Windows + Other Key like M to send the key you want http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm

C. write a low level keyboard hook ( I know it is possible but do not know c nor have the device driver kit to try)

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use AutoHotKey to set up your own key combo or character replacement.

Check out the documentation to find something you're comfortable with, but here's the basic formula. This one will => on the combo Windows + . (since > is the uppercase of .)

```
#.::
SendInput {=}{>}
return
```

or

```
#.::
SendInput {Space}{=}{>}{Space}
return
```

if you'd like it to automatically space before and after the lambda